# Android 4.4 rotate animation blinks when animating nested view

Tags: android, android-animation

I noticed a very strange situation when migrated my android app to 4.4 Suddenly the rotate animation in my HUD component started to blink and not working. I am trying to rotate object like this:

```
rotateAnimation = new RotateAnimation(180, 360, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
        0.5f,  Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
rotateAnimation.setDuration(1000);
rotateAnimation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
rotateAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
```

and:

```
public static void rotate(final View view) {

if(view.getAnimation() != null) {
    view.getAnimation().cancel();
    view.clearAnimation();
}

view.setAnimation(rotateAnimation);
view.getAnimation().start();
```

}

The code above works just fine when used on any other not nested view object, but when used for `ImageView` included with the include tag it simply does not work. Whats strange, other animations on the same object called within the same context works. Is this a 4.4 bug? I Include the view as follows:

```
    <include
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/view_trip_hud"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>
```

And the HUD component itself looks like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:alpha="0.6"
    android:background="@drawable/background_texture_dark"
    tools:context=".app.ui.fragment.TripSummaryFragment"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutHUDContainer">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/ui_default_element_margin">

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewTrackingStatus"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/status_preparing"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewDriveQuality"
                style="@style/HUDFont"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="@string/track_status_inactive"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <view
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutHUDCurrentSpeed"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        class="pl.com.infinitysoftware.carassistant.util.ui.HUDBlockLayout"
        style="@style/HUDBlock"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/ui_min_element_margin">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewCurrentSpeed"
            style="@style/HUDFont"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="-,-Km/h"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"/>
        </view>

    <view
        class="pl.com.infinitysoftware.carassistant.util.ui.HUDBlockLayout"
        style="@style/HUDBlock"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutHUDCurrentDistance"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/linearLayoutHUDCurrentSpeed"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/ui_min_element_margin">

        <TextView
            style="@style/HUDFont"
            android:id="@+id/textViewCurrentDistance"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="25 Km"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" />
    </view>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had a similar issue:

Try to set the view you are applying the animation like this (during the time you animate it):

```
view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE,null);
//And then apply the animation
view.startAnimation(myAnimation);
```

Don´t forget to put this in your manifest:

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

Comment: When hardware acceleration is turned off, hardware layers behave exactly as software layers. Please read: [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE)

Comment: It stopped working in Android 5.0 (blinks again). Anyone knows whats going on?

Comment: in 5.0 I was able to fix it by adding android:layerType="hardware" to the view xml intead of dynamically calling view.setLayerType. Maybe this will help someone :)

Comment: Thanks, you just made my life easier.

Answer (score -1):

i find the solution for this problem. Object Animator worked for me very well.

```
ObjectAnimator floatingButtonAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(floatingActionButton,
ANIMATION_NAME, ANIMATION_STARTING_DEGREE, ANIMATION_ENDING_DEGREE);
floatingButtonAnimator.setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION).addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
  @Override
  public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
    super.onAnimationStart(animation);
  }

  @Override
  public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
    super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
    exchangeValues();
  }
});
floatingButtonAnimator.start();
```