# Card fliping is not smooth like ios

Tags: android, animation, fragment, flip

I want to flip the screen completely like ios. I used a sample it is flipping but it is not smooth.Here is my code. Please help me to solve this issue.

I used this for my flip animation

https://www.thedroidsonroids.com/blog/android/android-flipa-card-animation-exlpained/

Comment: what do you mean by smooth? not fast enough?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23193659/android-4-4-rotate-animation-blinks-when-animating-nested-view/26118166#26118166